# Proving Cauchy random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Trying to prove that if a random variable $T$ has  [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) 
with probability density function: $$f(x)= \frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}$$
then $X = \frac{1}{T}$
and $Y = \frac{2T}{1-T^2}$ are also Cauchy random variables.

Now, I realize that this specific form of PDF  is called a Standard Cauchy distribution  and if I am correct then $T$ is of the form:

$$  \frac{1}{e^{|t|}}  $$

My main problem here is that I don't understand if i should use the characteristic function of $T$ to prove that $X$ and $Y$ are Cauchy or use it's PDF.

I apologize if this question is too simple, just this problem got me confused with the Cauchy distribution and I want to get the right picture of how to approach this type of questions, any hint greatly appreciated.

Comment: The change of variables formula might help computing the PDF of $f(X)$, given the PDF of $X$...

Comment: Easier than Federico's suggestion: Cauchy distribution = tan(random angle). Then consider some transformations of the random angle (multiply by something, subtract from something...)

Comment: The first question is answered [here](http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/PDFs/StandardcauchyI.pdf). The second one is answered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/319362/119261), elaborating the argument of the answer below and the comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of obtaining a Cauchy random variable is as $T=\tan U$
where $U$ is a uniform random variable on the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.
Then $X=\cot U=\tan(\pi/2-U)$ and $Y=\tan 2U$. Now $\pi/2-U$ is uniform
on $(0,\pi)$. Thinking of this modulo $\pi$, it's essentially the same as
the distribution of $U$. Likewise $2U$ is uniform on $(-\pi,\pi)$.
Again modulo $\pi$, that's essentially the same distribution as $U$.